# Read tokens in VariantSection in SXA

Tags: sxa

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.

I'm trying to set href data attribute to a Variant section in a rendering variant.

I tried to override the `RenderVariantField` class as mentioned in the solution for [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16382/how-to-use-tokens-in-link-attributes-in-variantfield) and it worked and returned the correct value - but only when I use it inside a variant Field. However, when I use it inside a variant Section it returns nothing.

Any idea what I can add in order to read a data attribute inside a variant section?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `RenderVariantField` it will indeed work for a variantfield. If you want this in a section, you need to look into `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection` in the same `<renderVariantField>` pipeline.

You might want to check [Setting css class in SXA variant from content item](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/12806/237) or https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-tokens-in-sitecore-sxa-variant.html for some extra information about attributes on sections.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, this is exactly what i needed